# Which annotation should I use: @IdClass or @EmbeddedId

Tags: java, jpa, annotations, java-persistence-api

The `JPA` (Java Persistence API) specification has 2 different ways to specify entity composite keys: `@IdClass` and `@EmbeddedId`.

I'm using both annotations on my mapped entities, but it turns out to be a big mess to people who aren't very familiar with `JPA`.

I want to adopt only one way to specify composite keys. Which one is really the best? Why?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

I consider that `@EmbeddedId` is probably more verbose because with `@IdClass` you cannot access the entire primary key object using any field access operator. Using the `@EmbeddedId` you can do like this:

```
@Embeddable class EmployeeId { name, dataOfBirth }
@Entity class Employee {
  @EmbeddedId EmployeeId employeeId;
  ...
}
```

This gives a clear notion of the fields that make the composite key because they are all aggregated in a class that is accessed trough a field access operator.

Another difference with `@IdClass` and `@EmbeddedId` is when it comes to write HQL :

With `@IdClass` you write:

```
select e.name from Employee e
```

and with `@EmbeddedId` you have to write:

```
select e.employeeId.name from Employee e
```

You have to write more text for the same query. Some may argue that this differs from a more natural language like the one promoted by `IdClass`. But most of the times understanding right from the query that a given field is part of the composite key is of invaluable help.

Comment: Though I agree with the explanation given above I would also like to add one unique use case for `@IdClass` even though I prefer `@EmbeddedId` in most situations (Got to know this from a session by Antonio Goncalves .What he suggested is we could use the `@IdClass` in case the composite key class is not accessible or comes in from another module or legacy code where we can't add a annotation .In those scenarios `@IdClass` will give us a way our .

Comment: I think it's possible that the cases for using the `@IdClass` annotation given by @Gaurav is the very reason that the JPA specification lists both methods of creating a composite key.. `@IdClass` and `@EmbeddidId`

Answer (score 29):

There are three strategies to use a compound primary key:

- Mark it as `@Embeddable` and add to your entity class a normal property for it, marked with `@Id`.
- Add to your entity class a normal property for it, marked with `@EmbeddedId`.
- Add properties to your entity class for all of its fields, mark them with `@Id`,and mark your entity class with `@IdClass`, supplying the class of your primary key class.

The use of `@Id` with a class marked as `@Embeddable` is the most natural approach. The `@Embeddable` tag can be used for non-primary key embeddable values anyway. It allows you to treat the compound primary key as a single property, and it permits the reuse of the `@Embeddable` class in other tables.

The next most natural approach is the use of the `@EmbeddedId` tag. Here, the primary key class cannot be used in other tables since it is not an `@Embeddable` entity, but it does allow us to treat the key as a
single attribute of some class.

Finally, the use of the `@IdClass` and `@Id` annotations allows us to map the compound primary key class using properties of the entity itself corresponding to the names of the properties in the primary key class. **The names must correspond** (there is no mechanism for overriding this), and the primary key class must honor the same obligations as with the other two techniques. The only advantage to this approach is its ability to “hide” the use of the primary key class from the interface of the enclosing entity. The `@IdClass` annotation takes a value parameter of Class type, which must be the class to be used as the compound primary key. **The fields that correspond to the properties of the primary key class to be used must all be annotated with `@Id`.**

Reference: http://www.apress.com/us/book/9781430228509

Answer (score 19):

I discovered an instance where I had to use EmbeddedId instead of IdClass. In this scenario there is a join table that has additional columns defined. I attempted to solve this problem using IdClass to represent the key of an entity that explicitly represents rows in the join table. I couldn't get it working this way. Thankfully "Java Persistence With Hibernate" has a section dedicated to this topic. One proposed solution was very similar to mine but it used EmbeddedId instead. I modeled my objects after those in the book it now behaves correctly.

Answer (score 18):

As far as I know, if your composite PK contains FK it's easier and more straightforward to use `@IdClass`

With `@EmbeddedId` you have to define a mapping for your FK column twice, once in `@Embeddedable` and once for as i.e. `@ManyToOne` where `@ManyToOne` has to be read-only(`@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`) because you can't have one column set in two variables (possible conflicts).
So you have to set your FK using a simple type in `@Embeddedable`.

On the other site using `@IdClass` this situation can be handled much easier as shown in [Primary Keys through OneToOne and ManyToOne Relationships](http://web.archive.org/web/20150508144430/http://blog.theapplicationbox.com/2012/07/primary-keys-through-onetoone-and.html):

Example JPA 2.0 ManyToOne id annotation

```
...
@Entity
@IdClass(PhonePK.class)
public class Phone {
 
    @Id
    private String type;
 
    @ManyToOne
    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name="OWNER_ID", referencedColumnName="EMP_ID")
    private Employee owner;
    ...
}
```

Example JPA 2.0 id class

```
...
public class PhonePK {
    private String type;
    private long owner;
 
    public PhonePK() {}
 
    public PhonePK(String type, long owner) {
        this.type = type;
        this.owner = owner;
    }
 
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (object instanceof PhonePK) {
            PhonePK pk = (PhonePK)object;
            return type.equals(pk.type) && owner == pk.owner;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
 
    public int hashCode() {
        return type.hashCode() + owner;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just don't forget to add getters to your PK class

Comment: @Sonata why do we need the getters? I tried it without any getters/setters and it works fine

Comment: Thanks for the id class example! Although I ended up needing to implement Serializable as well. Also might as well add getters and setters, especially if your IDE can automatically generate them.

Answer (score 9):

I think the main advantage is that we could use `@GeneratedValue` for the id when using the `@IdClass`? I'm sure we can't use `@GeneratedValue` for `@EmbeddedId`.

Comment: Is it not possible to use @GeneratedValue in Embeddedid??

Comment: I have used it successfully with EmbeddedId but apparently it's support varies by DB.  This is also true about using it with IdClass.

The spec says: "The GeneratedValue annotation may only be portably used for simple (i.e., non-composite) primary keys."

Answer (score 6):

Composite Key must not have an `@Id` property when `@EmbeddedId` is used.

Answer (score 4):

With EmbeddedId you can use the IN clause in HQL, for example : `FROM Entity WHERE id IN :ids` where id is an EmbeddedId whereas it's pain to achieve the same result with IdClass you will want to do something like `FROM Entity WHERE idPartA = :idPartA0 AND idPartB = :idPartB0 .... OR idPartA = :idPartAN AND idPartB = :idPartBN`