# JPA/Hibernate: What's better for composite primary keys, @IdClass or @EmbeddedId implementations and why?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, composite-primary-key

what's better for JPA/Hibernate composite primary keys, `@IdClass` or `@EmbeddedId` implementations and why?

This is an intentionally naive question. I decided to use `@EmbeddedId` (for whatever reason) and I feel like I made the wrong choice. Dereferencing the embeddedId that contains the column properties is redundant and quite error-prone when coding.

Are there any more reasons for and/or against the other? Is the a recommendation by the JPA (spec)?

Comment: It appears to be. But it doesn't list more reasons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Pascal wrote here's part of the answer:

[Which annotation should I use: @IdClass or @EmbeddedId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212350/which-anotation-should-i-use-idclass-or-embeddedid)

In the end, I believe using `@IdClass` is much easier in practice, because you have to add the `embeddedId` property name to dereference PK properties, while these aren't written for all non-PK properties.

You always have to remember exactly which properties are part of a PK and those which are not. That complicates writing JPQL queries unneccessarily.

Also, AFAIK the JPA 2.0 spec allows you to put `@Id` onto `@XToX`/`@JoinColumn`/s properties and it introduces the `@MapsId` annotation, so that mapping identifying relationships (a.k.a. derived identifiers in JPA) are more natural to implement.

Answer (score 9):

First, if possible, avoid composite ids at all costs. But if you really need, I would recommend `@EmbeddedId`.

`@IdClass` is basically a leftover from EJB 2.1 times to make it easier from migrating from BMP. In some other rare corner cases it may be better than `@EmbeddedId` too. However, generally `@EmbeddedId` is better and more OO since it encapsulates the concept os the key much better in the object.

You may want to use `@AttributeOverride(s)` if you need in the key field.

I don't see why do you think that dereferencing the embedded id is redundant and error-prone.

Comment: Yes, you're right with your last sentence. If one would be using JPA 2.0 syntax, there wouldn't be any redundant fields on the entity class, so you'd have to always dereference the join columns, which seems to be preferable for all 4 composite key vatiants JPA 1.0 @IdClass, JPA 1.0 @EmbeddedId, JPA 2.0 @IdClass, and JPA 2.0 @EmbeddedId.

Comment: Can you explain why composite IDs are bad?

Answer (score 2):

I. Remember using idclass to do it. But I'd recommend doing everything you can to avoid multi field keys. They just create extra work.

Comment: Gave +1 'cause it did make us re-evaluate using composite PK and have come to conclusion we'd be much better off w/o them.

Comment: Sometimes - especially when working with a legacy schema - the only way to correctly map an entity is by using composite PKs. Of course when designing a new schema it is better to avoid them (if possible).