# JPA/Hibernate and composite keys

Tags: jpa, composite-primary-key

I have come across some **SO** discussions and others posts (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024800/jpa-hibernate-whats-better-for-composite-primary-keys-idclass-or-embeddedid), [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/os-hibernatejpa/) and [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/486475/ORM/databases/JPA-composite-primary-key-classes)) where using composite primary keys with **JPA** is described either as something to be avoided if possible, or as a necessity due to legacy databases or as having "hairy" corner cases. Since we are designing a new database from scratch and don't have any legacy issues to consider is it recommended or let's say, safer, to avoid composite primary keys with **JPA** (either **Hibernate** or **EclipseLink**?).

My own feeling is that since **JPA** engines are complex enough and certainly, like all software, not without bugs, it may be best to suffer non-normalized tables than to endure the horror of running against a bug related to composite primary keys (the rationale being that numeric single-column primary keys and foreign keys are the simplest use case for JPA engines to support and so it should be as bug-free as possible).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've tried both methods, and personally I prefer avoiding composite primary keys for several reasons:

- You can make a superclass containing the id field, so you don't have to bother with it in all your entities.
- Entity creation becomes much easier
- JPA plays nicer in general
- Referencing to an entity becomes easier. For example storing a bunch of IDs in a set, or specififying a single id in the query string of a web page is largelly simplified by only having to use a single number.
- You can use a single equals method specified in the super class that works for all entities).
- If you use JSF you can make a generic converter
- Easier to specify objects when working with your DB client

But it brings some bad parts aswell:

- Small amount of denormalization
- Working with unpersisted objects (if you use auto generated IDs, which you should) can mean trouble in some cases, since equality methods and such needs an ID to work correctly