# JPA, Hibernate can I do composite primary key which one element is foreign kay @OneToMany?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys, entity, composite-primary-key

I would like to have in my entity composite primary key consisting of 2 columns (attributes), and have one of them to be foreign key simultaneously.

I write something like this, but don't know whether it works cause foreign key is marked as generated value in IntelliJ data source

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "service_point")
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@IdClass(ServicePointId.class)
public class ServicePoint {

    private Long providerId;
    private Integer servicePointNumber;

    private Provider provider;

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "provider_id", nullable = false, insertable = false,
            updatable = false, columnDefinition = "BIGINT UNSIGNED")
    public Long getProviderId() {
        return providerId;
    }

    public void setProviderId(Long providerId) {
        this.providerId = providerId;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "service_point_no", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "BIGINT UNSIGNED")
    public Integer getServicePointNumber() {
        return servicePointNumber;
    }

    public void setServicePointNumber(Integer servicePointNumber) {
        this.servicePointNumber = servicePointNumber;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "provider_id")
    public Provider getProvider() {
        return provider;
    }

    public void setProvider(Provider provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }
}
```

**UPDATED:**

I have tested Brian Vosburgh and it works:

```
transaction.begin();

em.persist(provider);

ServicePoint servicePoint = new ServicePoint(provider, 1);

em.persist(servicePoint);

transaction.commit();

ServicePoint servicePoint2 = em.find(ServicePoint.class,
        new ServicePointId(provider.getUserId(), servicePoint.getServicePointNumber()));

assertTrue("Service point provider id and Provider provider id should be the same.",
        servicePoint2.getProvider().getUserId() == provider.getUserId());
assertNotNull("Service point number can not be null", servicePoint2.getServicePointNumber());
assertEquals(servicePoint2.getProvider(), provider);

transaction.begin();
em.remove(servicePoint);
em.remove(provider);
transaction.commit();
```

**UPDATE 2 - new problem in next relationship composite PK (3 columns) and 2 of them are composite FK**
I have been trying to resemble the below solution and couldn't get through
 how to write ServicePointPhotoId @IdClass

[image: extentions of previous example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of the `providerId` field and its corresponding getter and setter. Add an `@Id` annotation to `getProvider()`. Define the `IdClass` like this:

```
public class ServicePointId {
    private Long provider;
    private Integer servicePointNumber;
    public Integer getProvider() {
        return provider;
    }
    public void setProvider(Integer provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }
    public Integer getServicePointNumber() {
        return servicePointNumber;
    }
    public void setServicePointNumber(Integer servicePointNumber) {
        this.servicePointNumber = servicePointNumber;
    }
}
```

Note that the property name in the `IdClass` matches the property name in the `Entity` (i.e. `provider`), but the properties' types are different. In the `IdClass` the property type must match the type of the `Id` property of `Provider`.

This is discussed in the JPA 2.1 spec, section 2.4.1.

Suggestion for UPDATE 2:

```
public class ServicePointPhotoId {
    public ServicePointId servicePoint;
    public Long photoId;
}

@Entity
@IdClass(ServicePointPhotoId.class)
@Table(name="service_point_photo")
public class ServicePointPhoto {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="provider_id", referencedColumnName="provider_id"),
        @JoinColumn(name="service_point_no", referencedColumnName="service_point_no")
    })
    private ServicePoint servicePoint;

    @Id
    @Column(name="photo_id")
    private Long photoId;
}
```

Note the attribute name must match (i.e. `servicePoint`); but the `IdClass` attribute's type must match the referenced `Entity`'s `IdClass` (i.e. `ServicePointId`).

I have used field annotations, but you can convert those to property annotations.

Again: the JPA 2.1 spec has an example of just this sort of relationship in section 2.4.1.3.

Comment: I'm testing this solution and consider if there is possibility to do something like:  1) em.persist(provider); ServicePoint servicePoint = new ServicePoint(provider); em.persist(servicePoint);  and auto generated only servicePointNumber.    2) Could i remain in IdClass providerId and use @MapsId("provider_id") on provider in ServicePoint?

Comment: Ok this solution seems to work correctly could you tell me if such approach will be ok or better will be to use .@EmbeddedId instead of @IdClass.  If I say about auto generated servicePointNumber I mean if I add new ServicePoint(provider) than for provider id ex. 5 i get generated next for example point 3 -> (5,3), but this isn't just autoicremented so (5,3),  (4,3), (1,3)  = (providerId, servicePointNo) will be allowed

Comment: I prefer using `@EmbeddedID` as it reduces the duplication of all the attributes in two classes and the chance of them getting out of sync. I have always thought `@IdClass` was in the spec to be consistent with the technique used by the pre-JPA spec Container Managed Persistence.

Comment: Edited answer to add suggestion for UPDATE 2

Comment: ok thx, actually I do it also myself based on this reference JPA 2.1 spec, section 2.4.1.3 which you recommended :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do composite primary keys is to use the [@EmbeddedId](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EmbeddedId.html) with a corresponding `@Embeddable` class.

Of our 400-odd database Entities, about 135 used Embedded ID classes to implement composite (multi-field) primary keys.

There are lots of questions and answers here on SO with examples of these.

Comment: Is there any crucial difference in using .@EmbeddedId instead of .@IdClass ?

Comment: @Michael See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212350/which-annotation-should-i-use-idclass-or-embeddedid) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024800/jpa-hibernate-whats-better-for-composite-primary-keys-idclass-or-embeddedid) here at SO for some discussion about the difference. We were taught the `@EmbeddedId` way by our SUN Microsystems mentor back in 2006 when we first started our EJB3 stuff. I believe that `@EmbeddedId` is the newer, more OO way to do composite keys.