# Spring JPA saving distinct entities with composite primary key not working as expected, updates same entity

Tags: spring, jpa, composite-primary-key, persist

I have a logic that saves some data and I use spring boot + spring data jpa.

Now, I have to save one object, and after moment, I have to save another objeect.
those of object consists of three primary key properties.
- **partCode, setCode, itemCode**.

let's say first object has a toString() returning below:

**SetItem(partCode=10-001, setCode=04, itemCode=01-0021, qty=1.0, sortNo=2, item=null)**

and the second object has a toString returning below:

**SetItem(partCode=10-001, setCode=04, itemCode=01-0031, qty=1.0, sortNo=2, item=null)**

there is a difference on itemCode value, and itemCode property is belonged to primary key, so the two objects are different each other.

but in my case, when I run the program, the webapp saves first object, and updates first object with second object value, not saving objects seperately.

[image]

(above image contains different values from this post question)

Here is my entity information:

```
/**
 * The persistent class for the set_item database table.
 *
 */
@Data
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Entity
@ToString(includeFieldNames=true)
@Table(name="set_item")
@IdClass(SetGroupId.class)
public class SetItem  extends BasicJpaModel<SetItemId> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="PART_CODE")
    private String partCode;

    @Id
    @Column(name="SET_CODE")
    private String setCode;

    @Id
    @Column(name="ITEM_CODE")
    private String itemCode;

    private Double qty;

    @Column(name="SORT_NO")
    private int sortNo;

    @Override
    public SetItemId getId() {

        if(BooleanUtils.ifNull(partCode, setCode, itemCode)){
            return null;
        }
        return SetItemId.of(partCode, setCode, itemCode);
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns(value = {
            @JoinColumn(name="PART_CODE", referencedColumnName="PART_CODE", insertable=false, updatable=false)
            , @JoinColumn(name="ITEM_CODE", referencedColumnName="ITEM_CODE", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
    private List<Item> item;

}
```

**So the question is,
how do I save objects separately which the objects' composite primary keys are partially same amongst them.**

**EDIT:**
The entity extends below class:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@MappedSuperclass
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
public abstract class BasicJpaModel<PK extends Serializable> implements Persistable<PK>, Serializable {

    @Override
    @JsonIgnore
    public boolean isNew() {
        return null == getId();
    }
}
```

**EDIT again**: embeddable class. 
after soneone points out embeddable class, I noticed there are only just two properties, it should be three of it. thank you.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor(staticName="of")
@Embeddable
public class SetGroupId implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @NonNull
    private String partCode;

    @NonNull
    private String setCode;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check howto use `@EmbeddedId` & `@Embeddable` (update you might need to use `AttributeOverrides` in id field, not sure if `Column`s in `@Embeddable` works).

You could create class annotated `@Embeddable` and add all those three ID fields there.

```
@Embeddable
public class MyId {
   private String partCode;
   private String setCode;
   private String itemCode;     
}
```

Add needed getters & setters.

Then set in class `SetItem` this class to be the id like `@EmbeddedId´.

```
public class SetItem {

   @EmbeddedId
   @AttributeOverrides({
      @AttributeOverride(name="partCode",
                         column=@Column(name="PART_CODE")),
      @AttributeOverride(name="setCode",
                         column=@Column(name="SET_CODE"))
      @AttributeOverride(name="itemCode",
                         column=@Column(name="ITEM_CODE"))
   })
   MyId id;
```

Check also [Which annotation should I use: @IdClass or @EmbeddedId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212350/which-annotation-should-i-use-idclass-or-embeddedid)

Comment: Thank you. I saw my embeddable class. and there are only just two properties, not three. so I will change this, and see what happen. really thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to implement equals and hashCode in SetGroupId.

Can you provide that class?

Comment: Good idea, thank you. I will implement that methods too