# compound key and CrudRepository in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have the following entity :

```
@Entity
public class Attendance implements Serializable{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @ManyToOne
        private Student student;
        @Id
        @ManyToOne
        private Session session;
        ...
```

as you can see, the primary key is composed of two classes, and the CrudRepository accepts only one type as primary key (CrudRepository), how can I solve the problem please?
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want 2 PK in your table? A PK should be unique

Comment: because there is a many to many relation between Student and Session with extra fields, check this link : https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: I read it in diagonal and I didn't see any entity with 2 `@Id`. I saw `@MapsId` which has different meaning. By the way, you can't have 2 `@Id` in the same entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a composite key. You can do this in different ways.
You can use `@EmbeddedId` and `@Embeddable` or you can use `@IdClass` (here you have more than one @id in your entity class)

See also:
[Which annotation should I use: @IdClass or @EmbeddedId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212350/which-annotation-should-i-use-idclass-or-embeddedid)