# @ManyToOne mapping for Composite Primary Key @IdClass

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a table 'metadata' (single column PK) and another table 'business_logic' (Composite PK) as follows:

```sql
create table metadata (
    id  bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(60) NOT NULL
);

create table business_logic (
    business_id bigint,
    id varchar(60),
    description varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (business_id, id),
    FOREIGN KEY (business_id) REFERENCES metadata(id)
);
```

I have created Java classes as below

```java
//Metadata.java
@Entity @Data
public class Metadata {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;
}

//BusinessLogic.java
@Data @Entity
@IdClass( BusinessLogicPk.class )
public class BusinessLogic {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne( targetEntity = Metadata.class )
    @JoinColumn( name = "business_id", referencedColumnName = "id" )
    private Long businessId;

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String description;
}

//BusinessLogicPk.java
@Data
public class BusinessLogicPk implements Serializable {
    private Long businessId;
    private String id;
}

//BusinessLogicRepository.java
public interface BusinessLogicRepository extends JpaRepository<BusinessLogic, BusinessLogicPk> {
}
```

When I try to call `businessLogicRepository.findAll()` function, it throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field com.example.jpademo.repository.entity.BusinessLogicPk.businessId to com.example.jpademo.repository.entity.Business
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:780) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterFieldImpl.set(SetterFieldImpl.java:52) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.setPropertyValues(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer.setPropertyValues(PojoComponentTuplizer.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.setPropertyValues(ComponentType.java:450) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:697) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:881) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:735) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowsFromResultSet(Loader.java:1047) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:998) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:967) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:357) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2868) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2682) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2677) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:540) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1459) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1649) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:427) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:530) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:286) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:640) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:76) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:241) ~[spring-aop-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy107.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.jpademo.controller.QuestionsController.fetchQuestions(QuestionsController.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:529) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

I guess this is due to using the field `Long businessId` instead of `Business business`, If I replace it this way, this throws a new error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Property of @IdClass not found in entity com.example.jpademo.repository.entity.BusinessLogic: businessId
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.fillComponent(AnnotationBinder.java:2793) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindIdClass(AnnotationBinder.java:2919) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.mapAsIdClass(AnnotationBinder.java:1052) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:778) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:225) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to official documentation of [hibernate 6](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/introduction/html_single/Hibernate_Introduction.html).

> Now the entity class may reuse this definition using `@EmbeddedId`, and the `@IdClass` annotation is no longer required.

Your entity mapping will look so:

**BusinessLogic entity class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "business_logic")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class BusinessLogic {

  @EmbeddedId
  private BusinessLogicId businessLoggicId;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "business_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
  private Metadata businessId;

  private String description;
}
```

**Metadata entity class:**

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "metadata")
public class Metadata {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private String name;
}
```

Embeddable id class that meet your requirements to have a entity with a PK that is combined by FK and default one.

```
@Embeddable
public class BusinessLogicId implements Serializable {

  private Long business_id;

  private Long id;

}
```

And of course the result that I got after invoke findAll() method from `BusinessLogicRepo`

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks Lisa, Just wondering, does it not work at all with @IdClass ?

Comment: of course it will work, i think you should read it [embeddable-objects](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/introduction/html_single/Hibernate_Introduction.html#embeddable-objects) and also some good answers about this topic witch one to use [idclass-or-embeddedid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212350/which-annotation-should-i-use-idclass-or-embeddedid)