# java : should data of @Id field in entity be unique to one another?

Tags: java, jpa, lombok

I'm curious whether should the field with @Id annotation be unique to one another or not.

The reason why i'm asking this is that I'm creating an entity with three fields to act as a
primary key (but declaring them as EmbeddedId hasn't been done), and I need to make a logic
when I want to search a set of rows from database with just one @Id field.

So I will not declare primary key in the table which is mapped to that entity, and I want to use
just one field so that I can read a list of data that matches with it.

I've tried @EmbeddedId, but it didn't seem to function as I expected.

Comment: Could you define "it didn't seem to function" as you expected? If you are looking for 1 of three properties that are required to uniquely identify a row/entity, I hope you are not trying to populate a key class and leave the other attributes as null and rely on 'find' logic. You'll need a special query that returns a list to search on that 1 attribute, as multiple rows could share that value.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**No.**

I'm not sure why `@EmbeddedId` isn't working for you, but I would suggest trying the `@IdClass` annotation.
`@IdClass` is similar to `@EmbeddedId`, but it aligns more closely with the RDB schema. It doesn't require a second depth of access like `entity.getId().getField()` to reach the fields of the primary key class.

If you want more info about difference of each annotation look [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212350/which-annotation-should-i-use-idclass-or-embeddedid).

Here's sample code:

- Entity

```java
@Entity
@IdClass(SampleEntityId.class)
public class SampleEntity {

 @Id
 private Integer id1;

 @Id
 private Integer id2;

 @Id
 private Integer id3;
}
```

- SampleEntityId

```java
public class SampleEntityId implements Serializable {
  private Integer id1;
  private Integer id2;
  private Integer id3;
}
```